# Using ng-class from a nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested ng-repeat list, and I want to add a class to the parent one when any item from the nested list is modified.

It looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products" ng-class="{full: vari.basket>0}">
    <div ng-repeat="vari in pa.variacions">
       <input type="number" ng-model="vari.basket" name="basket" min="0" max="20" step="1" ng-init="vari.basket=0">
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically I want to add the `full` class when any of the vari items has a basket > 0.

So far is not working, what am I missing?

Comment: Your `ng-class` attribute is outside the scope of `vari`

Comment: You'll have to provide the outer `ngRepeat` with a mechanism to determine if any of the `pa.variacions` have items.  The outer `ngRepeat` can't reach into the `$scope` or the child `ngRepeat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a function in your controller that sets the class for your parent.

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products" ng-class="{full: isFull(pa.variacions)}">
    <div ng-repeat="vari in pa.variacions">
       <input type="number" ng-model="vari.basket" name="basket" min="0" max="20" step="1" ng-init="vari.basket=0">
    </div>
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.isFull = function(variacions) {
  if (!Array.isArray(variacions)) {
    return false;
  }

  return variacions.find(vari => vari.basket > 0);
}
```

Comment: Is returning `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` in some items, as some items have no nested ng-repeat... Any workaround?

Comment: sure, I updated to check if the item is an array before running the `find`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products" ng-class="{true: 'myFullClass'}[$ctrl.isProductBasketFull(pa)]">
    <div ng-repeat="vari in pa.variacions">
        <input type="number" ng-model="vari.basket" name="basket" min="0" max="20" step="1" ng-init="vari.basket=0">
    </div>
</div>
```

This isn't an ideal solution because of all the loops that would be generated but you could pass `pa` to a controller function that determines if a `vari` basket is full then return a boolean value.

In controller:

```
$scope.isProductBasketFull = function(pa){
    for(var i=0,cnt=pa.length;i<cnt;i++)
        if(pa[i].basket === maxVal) // whatever your max value is
            return true;
    return false;
};
```

Comment: mcranston18 is a better solution